# In Objective-C, what's the advantage of having a singleton over a class method?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

As above, but careful, I'm only interested in Objective-C context, so there is no point in pointing out the advantages of a singleton over a static methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say nothing. Singletons are often considered bad practice and this applies to Obejctive-C as well. One thing that might make singletons a better solution than class methods is that singletons are proper instances that can access instance variables, so if one needs the class to store data in ivars, singletons can be a solution. (But well, even implementing singletons often requires using static global or local variables - so strictly speaking, you can't really avoid them entirely, at most you can reduce their number to one.)

Comment: Out of the "two evils", singletons have the advantage of, theoretically, being stubbed: i.e. the "get instance" can return any conforming object. I generally prefer to avoid both.

Comment: @pst yep, consider `+ [NSString stringWithString:@"Constant"]` - that's essentially implemented as a singleton, and it returns `__NSConstantString`.

Answer (score 2):

One significant advantage is class methods in Objective-C can't hold onto any data (unless declared as static within the method).  Whereas with a singleton, you have access to all of the data of the single-instance

Comment: Well... class methods can store data in statics, which are -- effectively -- like singleton storage *but doing so makes it exceedingly difficult to refactor into a non-singleton pattern*.

Comment: @bbum yes, but that storage isn't inherent to the class method.  Unlike C++ or Java, you don't get inherent access to "class level variables"

Comment: Not really much of a difference;  a static local is scoped to the compilation unit and not visible outside.  Certainly, you can define multiple classes in a file, but that is about the only difference outside of the requirement to go through the class interface to get to the state.  Or you can put the static inside a method implementation, limiting the scope further (though changing the value then becomes single-method-does-both-get-and-set, which is just silly). The point, though: Class vs. singleton matters little on the storage front beyond the refactorability (and, yes, that is my upvote).